# Insert mongo script through c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert

I have a collection of files in mongo, they are already in insert format and the scripts work when I run it manually and directly in mongoDb.

However, I am creating a tool to automate this function, but I got stuck when trying to convert the string to "bson".

Exemple script mongo:

```
db.getCollection('fs.files').insert({'metadata' : {'MARCA': 'BP','DATAINICIAL' : '14/09/2020', 'DATAFINAL' : '14/09/2020', 'NOME' : 'USER TEST', 'FICHA' : 'A123456', 'NOMEARQUIVO' : 'potato.pdf'},'filename': 'potato.pdf','fileSource': 'potato.pdf','ContentType': 'application/pdf',ISODate('2022-05-13T03:55:17Z')});
```

my function in c#:

```
            var client = new MongoClient(con);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("archives");

            //Cria o bson usando a linha de arquivo passada em "row".
            BsonDocument document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(row);

            try
            { 
                var doc = BsonDocument.Create(document);

                return true;
            }
            catch (MongoWriteException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Row is my archive string:

```
db.getCollection('fs.files').insert({'metadata' : {'MARCA': 'BP','DATAINICIAL' : '14/09/2020', 'DATAFINAL' : '14/09/2020', 'NOME' : 'USER TEST', 'FICHA' : 'A123456', 'NOMEARQUIVO' : 'potato.pdf'},'filename': 'potato.pdf','fileSource': 'potato.pdf','ContentType': 'application/pdf',ISODate('2022-05-13T03:55:17Z')});
```

I have more millions rows for input in mongoDb.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpCBe.png)

When i start my oriject, receave this error:

I've been stuck on this for a day, thanks for the support

Comment: What is it in `row`?

Comment: Row is a string archive - db.getCollection('fs.files').insert({'metadata' : {'MARCA': 'BP','DATAINICIAL' : '14/09/2020', 'DATAFINAL' : '14/09/2020', 'NOME' : 'USER TEST', 'FICHA' : 'A123456', 'NOMEARQUIVO' : 'potato.pdf'},'filename': 'potato.pdf','fileSource': 'potato.pdf','ContentType': 'application/pdf',ISODate('2022-05-13T03:55:17Z')});

Answer (score 0):

please try BsonDocument.Parse(row)
Assumption: row is a string field in the model.

Comment: Hi, Chandana, I try it, but don't solve the error:
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.

About the var "Row", yes, it is my string: 

```
db.getCollection('fs.files').insert({'metadata' : {'MARCA': 'BP','DATAINICIAL' : '14/09/2020', 'DATAFINAL' : '14/09/2020', 'NOME' : 'USER TEST', 'FICHA' : 'A123456', 'NOMEARQUIVO' : 'potato.pdf'},'filename': 'potato.pdf','fileSource': 'potato.pdf','ContentType': 'application/pdf',ISODate('2022-05-13T03:55:17Z')});
```

Comment: your json is invalid, before ISODate you should have a key

Comment: Hello, dodo.
But if I run this json in noSQLBooster it will include the line in mongoDb. I already tried the insert manually. I wanted to make a mongoimport-like process, however, taking raw records like this that have "db.getCollection('fs.files').insert({ });"